# When a transaction is rolled back in timestamp ordering protocol why is it given a new timestamp?

Tags: database, relational-database, optimistic-concurrency

When a transaction is rolled back in timestamp ordering protocol, why is it given a new timestamp?
Why don`t we retain the old timestamp?

Comment: well this is how I got the question .

Comment: Please edit your question to give a bit more detail, to explain the point you need explaining.  Why should we put effort into answering your question if you aren't prepared to spend sufficient effort framing it properly?

Comment: The question is actually quite clear if your area of expertise covers the topic being asked about.  If you don't know about timestamp ordering database concurrency protocols, it is as opaque as mud, true, but the same is true of some questions about C# and ASP.NET and ...

Answer (score 6):

If you are talking of a *scheduler* whose operation is timestamp-based, and a rolled-back transaction were allowed to "re-enter the scheduling queue" with its 'old' timestamp, then the net effect might be that the scheduler immediately gives the highest priority to any request coming from that transaction, and the net effect of THAT might be that whatever problem caused that transaction to roll back, re-appears almost instantaneously, perhaps causing a new rollback, which causes a new "re-entering the schedule queue", etc. etc.

Or the net effect of that "immediately re-entering the queue" could be that all other transactions are stalled.

Think of a queue of persons in the post office, and there is someone with a request which cannot be served, and that person were allowed to immediately re-enter the queue at the front (instead of at the back).  How long would it then take before it gets to be your turn ?

Comment: The reasoing I gave was : If Transaction T issues a read(q) and the W-timestamp associated with q is gretaer than that of T , it means T is trying to read to read a value of q that is changed . So it is rolled back and is given a new timestamp . So it will be ablee to execute read(q) . If old timestamp is retained , it will keep on getting rolled back as timestamp goes on increasing . is it plausible?

Comment: It seems I completely missed the point of your question.  However, when I googled for "timestamp ordering protocol", the first two result lines are a PDF and a PPT from cs.virginia.edu and cs.ust.hk that seem to contain at least clues for the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

Because there could be other transactions that had committed with the new timestamp

- Initial timestamp is at X
- Transaction T1 starts
- T1 allocates timestamp increments it to value to X+1
- Transaction T2 starts
- T2 allocates timestamp increments it to value to X+2
- T2 commits
- T1 rolls back

If T1 would rollback the timestamp to X then a third transaction would generate a conflict with T2's allocated value. Same goes for increment and sequences. If you need monolithic sequence values (no gaps) then the transactions have to serialize and this happens at the price of dismal performance.

Comment: The reasoing I gave was : If Transaction T issues a read(q) and the W-timestamp associated  with q is  gretaer  than that  of  T , it  means  T is  trying  to read  to  read  a  value  of  q  that is changed  . So   it  is  rolled  back  and  is  given  a new timestamp . So it will be  ablee  to execute read(q) . If old timestamp is  retained ,  it will keep on getting rolled back as timestamp  goes on increasing . is it plausible?

Comment: I misread the question. Your question is strictly about the timestamp-ordering protocol (ie. similar to snapshot isolation). I answered a practical question about timestamps (ie. the ROWVERSION  data type) in databases.

Answer (score 0):

In a timestamp ordering protocol, the timestamp assigned to the transaction when starting is used to identify potential conflicts with other transactions. These could be transactions that updated an object this transaction is trying to read or transactions that read the value this transaction is trying to overwrite. As a result, when a transaction is aborted and restarted (i.e. to maintain serializability), then all the operations of the transaction will be executed anew and this is the reason a new timestamp needs to be assigned.

From a theoretical perspective, rerunning the operations again while the transaction is still using the old timestamp would be incorrect & unsafe, since it would be reading/overwriting new values while thinking it's situated in an older moment in time. From a practical perspective, if the transaction keeps using the old timestamp, most likely it will keep aborting & restarting continuously, since it will keep conflicting with the same transactions again and again.